# How do I get the progress bar percentage to a textview in Android?

Tags: android

I'm using Download manager to download a file from internet and also added a progress bar in the activity. I want to get the percentage of downloading file according to the progress bar , to a textbox in Android. This is what I tried up to now.

```
protected ProgressBar mProgressBar;
protected long downloadId;
private  DownloadManager downloadmanager;


public void startDownload() {


    String servicestring = Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE;

    downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(servicestring);

    Uri uri = Uri
            .parse("http://filename.mp3");
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);



    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Download", "Sinhala.mp3");
    downloadId = downloadmanager.enqueue(request);

    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
            q.setFilterById(downloadId);
            Cursor cursor = downloadmanager.query(q);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
            int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
            cursor.close();

            final int dl_progress = (bytes_downloaded * 100 / bytes_total);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){

                    mProgressBar.setProgress(dl_progress);

                }
            });

        }

    }, 0, 10);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ThinDownloadManager downloadManager;
private static final int DOWNLOAD_THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 4;

Button mDownload1;
Button mDownload2;
Button mDownload3;
Button mDownload4;
Button mDownload5;

Button mStartAll;
Button mCancelAll;
Button mListFiles;

ProgressBar mProgress1;
ProgressBar mProgress2;
ProgressBar mProgress3;
ProgressBar mProgress4;
ProgressBar mProgress5;

TextView mProgress1Txt;
TextView mProgress2Txt;
TextView mProgress3Txt;
TextView mProgress4Txt;
TextView mProgress5Txt;

private static final String FILE1 = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25887355/test_photo1.JPG";
private static final String FILE2 = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25887355/test_photo2.jpg";
private static final String FILE3 = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25887355/test_song.mp3";
private static final String FILE4 = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25887355/test_video.mp4";
private static final String FILE5 = "http://httpbin.org/headers";
private static final String FILE6 = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25887355/ThinDownloadManager.tar.gz";

MyDownloadDownloadStatusListenerV1
    myDownloadStatusListener = new MyDownloadDownloadStatusListenerV1();

int downloadId1;
int downloadId2;
int downloadId3;
int downloadId4;
int downloadId5;
int downloadId6;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDownload1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mDownload2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mDownload3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    mDownload4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    mDownload5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_download_headers);

    mStartAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    mCancelAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    mListFiles = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);

    mProgress1Txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressTxt1);
    mProgress2Txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressTxt2);
    mProgress3Txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressTxt3);
    mProgress4Txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressTxt4);
    mProgress5Txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressTxt5);

    mProgress1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress1);
    mProgress2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress2);
    mProgress3 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress3);
    mProgress4 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress4);
    mProgress5 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress5);

    mProgress1.setMax(100);
    mProgress1.setProgress(0);

    mProgress2.setMax(100);
    mProgress2.setProgress(0);

    mProgress3.setMax(100);
    mProgress3.setProgress(0);

    mProgress4.setMax(100);
    mProgress4.setProgress(0);

    mProgress5.setMax(100);
    mProgress5.setProgress(0);

    downloadManager = new ThinDownloadManager(DOWNLOAD_THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy();

    File filesDir = getExternalFilesDir("");

    Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(FILE1);
    Uri destinationUri = Uri.parse(filesDir+"/test_photo1.JPG");
    final DownloadRequest downloadRequest1 = new DownloadRequest(downloadUri)
            .setDestinationURI(destinationUri).setPriority(DownloadRequest.Priority.LOW)
            .setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy)
            .setDownloadContext("Download1")
            .setStatusListener(myDownloadStatusListener);

    downloadUri = Uri.parse(FILE2);
    destinationUri = Uri.parse(filesDir+"/test_photo2.jpg");
    final DownloadRequest downloadRequest2 = new DownloadRequest(downloadUri)
            .setDestinationURI(destinationUri).setPriority(DownloadRequest.Priority.LOW)
            .setDownloadContext("Download2")
            .setStatusListener(myDownloadStatusListener);

    downloadUri = Uri.parse(FILE3);
    destinationUri = Uri.parse(filesDir+"/test_song.mp3");
    final DownloadRequest downloadRequest3 = new DownloadRequest(downloadUri)
            .setDestinationURI(destinationUri).setPriority(DownloadRequest.Priority.HIGH)
            .setDownloadContext("Download3")
            .setStatusListener(myDownloadStatusListener);

    downloadUri = Uri.parse(FILE4);
    destinationUri = Uri.parse(filesDir+"/mani/test/aaa/test_video.mp4");
    // Define a custom retry policy
    retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, 3, 2f);
    final DownloadRequest downloadRequest4 = new DownloadRequest(downloadUri)
            .setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy)
            .setDestinationURI(destinationUri).setPriority(DownloadRequest.Priority.HIGH)
            .setDownloadContext("Download4")
            .setStatusListener(myDownloadStatusListener);

    downloadUri = Uri.parse(FILE5);
    destinationUri = Uri.parse(filesDir+"/headers.json");
    final DownloadRequest downloadRequest5 = new DownloadRequest(downloadUri)
            .addCustomHeader("Auth-Token", "myTokenKey")
            .addCustomHeader("User-Agent", "Thin/Android")
            .setDestinationURI(destinationUri).setPriority(DownloadRequest.Priority.HIGH)
            .setDownloadContext("Download5")
            .setStatusListener(myDownloadStatusListener);

    downloadUri = Uri.parse(FILE6);
    destinationUri = Uri.parse(filesDir+"/wtfappengine.zip");
    final DownloadRequest downloadRequest6 = new DownloadRequest(downloadUri)
            .setDestinationURI(destinationUri).setPriority(DownloadRequest.Priority.HIGH)
            .setDownloadContext("Download6")
            .setStatusListener(myDownloadStatusListener);

    mDownload1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (downloadManager.query(downloadId1) == DownloadManager.STATUS_NOT_FOUND) {
                downloadId1 = downloadManager.add(downloadRequest1);
            }
        }
    });

    mDownload2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (downloadManager.query(downloadId2) == DownloadManager.STATUS_NOT_FOUND) {
                downloadId2 = downloadManager.add(downloadRequest2);
            }
        }
    });

    mDownload3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (downloadManager.query(downloadId3) == DownloadManager.STATUS_NOT_FOUND) {
                downloadId3 = downloadManager.add(downloadRequest3);
            }
        }
    });

    mDownload4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (downloadManager.query(downloadId4) == DownloadManager.STATUS_NOT_FOUND) {
                downloadId4 = downloadManager.add(downloadRequest4);
            }
        }
    });

    mDownload5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
            //if (downloadManager.query(downloadId5) == DownloadManager.STATUS_NOT_FOUND) {
            //    downloadId5 = downloadManager.add(downloadRequest5);
            //}

          if (downloadManager.query(downloadId6) == DownloadManager.STATUS_NOT_FOUND) {
              downloadId6 = downloadManager.add(downloadRequest6);
          }

      }
    });

    mStartAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            downloadManager.cancelAll();
            downloadId1 = downloadManager.add(downloadRequest1);
            downloadId2 = downloadManager.add(downloadRequest2);
            downloadId3 = downloadManager.add(downloadRequest3);
            downloadId4 = downloadManager.add(downloadRequest4);
            downloadId5 = downloadManager.add(downloadRequest5);
        }
    });

    mCancelAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            downloadManager.cancelAll();
        }
    });

    mListFiles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            showInternalFilesDir();
        }
    });

    mProgress1Txt.setText("Download1");
    mProgress2Txt.setText("Download2");
    mProgress3Txt.setText("Download3");
    mProgress4Txt.setText("Download4");
    mProgress5Txt.setText("Download5");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    System.out.println("######## onDestroy ######## ");
    downloadManager.release();
}

private void showInternalFilesDir() {
    File internalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir("").getPath());
    File files[] = internalFile.listFiles();
    String contentText = "";
    if( files.length == 0 ) {
        contentText = "No Files Found";
    }

    for (File file : files) {
        contentText += file.getName()+" "+file.length()+" \n\n ";
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    AlertDialog internalCacheDialog = builder.create();
    LayoutInflater inflater = internalCacheDialog.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_files, null);
    TextView content = (TextView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.filesList);
    content.setText(contentText);

    builder.setView(dialogLayout);
    builder.show();

}

class MyDownloadDownloadStatusListenerV1 implements DownloadStatusListenerV1 {

    @Override
    public void onDownloadComplete(DownloadRequest request) {
        final int id = request.getDownloadId();
        if (id == downloadId1) {
            mProgress1Txt.setText(request.getDownloadContext() + " id: "+id+" Completed");

        } else if (id == downloadId2) {
            mProgress2Txt.setText(request.getDownloadContext() + " id: "+id+" Completed");

        } else if (id == downloadId3) {
            mProgress3Txt.setText(request.getDownloadContext() + " id: "+id+" Completed");

        } else if (id == downloadId4) {
            mProgress4Txt.setText(request.getDownloadContext() + " id: "+id+" Completed");
        } else if (id == downloadId5) {
          mProgress5Txt.setText(request.getDownloadContext() + " id: "+id+" Completed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadFailed(DownloadRequest request, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
        final int id = request.getDownloadId();
        if (id == downloadId1) {
            mProgress1Txt.setText("Download1 id: "+id+" Failed: ErrorCode "+errorCode+", "+errorMessage);
            mProgress1.setProgress(0);
        } else if (id == downloadId2) {
            mProgress2Txt.setText("Download2 id: "+id+" Failed: ErrorCode "+errorCode+", "+errorMessage);
            mProgress2.setProgress(0);

        } else if (id == downloadId3) {
            mProgress3Txt.setText("Download3 id: "+id+" Failed: ErrorCode "+errorCode+", "+errorMessage);
            mProgress3.setProgress(0);

        } else if (id == downloadId4) {
            mProgress4Txt.setText("Download4 id: "+id+" Failed: ErrorCode "+errorCode+", "+errorMessage);
            mProgress4.setProgress(0);
        } else if (id == downloadId5) {
          mProgress5Txt.setText("Download5 id: "+id+" Failed: ErrorCode "+errorCode+", "+errorMessage);
          mProgress5.setProgress(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgress(DownloadRequest request, long totalBytes, long downloadedBytes, int progress) {
        int id = request.getDownloadId();

        System.out.println("######## onProgress ###### "+id+" : "+totalBytes+" : "+downloadedBytes+" : "+progress);
        if (id == downloadId1) {
            mProgress1Txt.setText("Download1 id: "+id+", "+progress+"%"+"  "+getBytesDownloaded(progress,totalBytes));
            mProgress1.setProgress(progress);

        } else if (id == downloadId2) {
            mProgress2Txt.setText("Download2 id: "+id+", "+progress+"%"+"  "+getBytesDownloaded(progress,totalBytes));
            mProgress2.setProgress(progress);

        } else if (id == downloadId3) {
            mProgress3Txt.setText("Download3 id: "+id+", "+progress+"%"+"  "+getBytesDownloaded(progress,totalBytes));
            mProgress3.setProgress(progress);

        } else if (id == downloadId4) {
            mProgress4Txt.setText("Download4 id: "+id+", "+progress+"%"+"  "+getBytesDownloaded(progress,totalBytes));
            mProgress4.setProgress(progress);
        } else if (id == downloadId5) {
          mProgress5Txt.setText("Download5 id: "+id+", "+progress+"%"+"  "+getBytesDownloaded(progress,totalBytes));
          mProgress5.setProgress(progress);
        } else if (id == downloadId6) {
            mProgress5Txt.setText("Download6 id: "+id+", "+progress+"%"+"  "+getBytesDownloaded(progress,totalBytes));
            mProgress5.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }
}

private String getBytesDownloaded(int progress, long totalBytes) {
    //Greater than 1 MB
    long bytesCompleted = (progress * totalBytes)/100;
    if (totalBytes >= 1000000) {
        return (""+(String.format("%.1f", (float)bytesCompleted/1000000))+ "/"+ ( String.format("%.1f", (float)totalBytes/1000000)) + "MB");
    } if (totalBytes >= 1000) {
        return (""+(String.format("%.1f", (float)bytesCompleted/1000))+ "/"+ ( String.format("%.1f", (float)totalBytes/1000)) + "Kb");

    } else {
        return ( ""+bytesCompleted+"/"+totalBytes );
    }
}
```

}